# How can I dynamically add more textfields according to what the user has entered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I add more textfield of `color` and `choose design` according to what the user has entered?

For example, the user has entered 5 in the field `quantity`. How can I make the fields `color` and `choose design` be repeated 5 times? Also how will the `useState` for the `color` and `choose design` be since this would be submitted? Should the `useState` be a `map` or an `array`? For now, I've used it as a `string` since I do not have any idea how will this work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Below are the codes:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [prod, setProd] = useState("");
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
  const [design, setDesign] = useState("");
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setProd(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeSize = (event) => {
    setSize(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeDesign = (event) => {
    setDesign(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(prod, qty, size, design);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Product</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={prod}
            label="Product"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value="Item1">Item1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Item2">Item2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Item3">Item3</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <br />
        <TextField
          type="number"
          label="Quantity"
          variant="outlined"
          value={qty}
          onChange={(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
          fullWidth
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Size</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={size}
            label="Product"
            onChange={handleChangeSize}
          >
            <MenuItem value="S">Small</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="M">Medium</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="L">Large</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <br />
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Choose Design</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={design}
            label="Product"
            onChange={handleChangeDesign}
          >
            <MenuItem value="Design1">Design1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Design2">Design2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Design3">Design3</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Button type="submit">Submit </Button>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-4g34r?file=/demo.js:0-2952

Comment: you probably need to create an `useEffect` to "keep an eye" on `qty` and then based on the you `map()` through the options to be displayed
`useEffect(() => {
    Number(qty) ? setDisplayMoreFields(true) : setDisplayMoreFields(false);
  }, [qty]);`
https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-ese4j?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since any help would be appreciated
I give you an example of how to do it using an array

note it would be better to set Add/Remove UX ways, and also use new class/component for every item, but for the purpose of the study, lets do it your way:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";

import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [prod, setProd] = useState("");
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(0);
  const [productArr,setProductArr] = useState([]);
  const [design, setDesign] = useState("");
  const [size, setSize] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    
    setProd(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeSize = (e,p) => {
    if(e && p){
      p.size = e.target.value;
      const updatedObject = productArr.map((product) =>
        product.key === p.key ? p : product
      );
      setProductArr(updatedObject);
    }
  };

  const handleChangeDesign = (e,p) => {
    if(e && p){
        p.design = e.target.value;
        const updatedObject = productArr.map((product) =>
        product.key === p.key ? p : product
      );
    setProductArr(updatedObject);
    }
  };

  const handleChangeQty = (event) => {
    setQty(event.target.value);
    while(productArr.length > 0) {
      productArr.pop();
    }
    let updateProductArr =[...productArr];
    for(let i=0;i<event.target.value;i++){
      updateProductArr.push(
        {
        key:i+1,
        size:'',
        design:''})
        
    }
    setProductArr(updateProductArr);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(prod, qty, size, design);
  };

  return (
  <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Product</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={prod}
            label="Product"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value="Item1">Item1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Item2">Item2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Item3">Item3</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
        <br />
        <br />
        <TextField
          type="number"
          label="Quantity"
          variant="outlined"
          value={qty}
          onChange={handleChangeQty}
          fullWidth
        />
        <br />
        <br />
        {
          productArr.map((product) => 
     (
    <div key={"div-"+product.key}>
     <p>{product.key}</p> 
    <FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label-{product.key}">Size</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId={"demo-simple-select-label-"+product.key}
      id={"demo-simple-select-"+product.key}
      value={product.size}
      label="Product"
      onChange={(e)=>handleChangeSize(e,product)}
    >
      <MenuItem value="S">Small</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="M">Medium</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="L">Large</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
  <br />
  <br />
  <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label-{product.key}">Choose Design</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId={"demo-simple-select-label-"+product.key}
            id={"demo-simple-select-"+product.key}
            value={product.design}
            label="Product"
            onChange={(e)=>handleChangeDesign(e,product)}
          >
            <MenuItem value="Design1">Design1</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Design2">Design2</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="Design3">Design3</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
        ))
        }
     
        <br />
        <br />
        <Button type="submit">Submit </Button>
      </form>
      <Button>Add more Product </Button>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-mcy5b?file=/demo.js

Comment: @Saral Foyerlicht Thank you. I'll try doing it in a way where the user can add or remove it for the sake of user experience.